# Open a site by C# browser language

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<div class="language">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <asp:LinkButton Text="TR" CausesValidation="false" ID="lnktr_TR" Visible="true" runat="server" OnClick="lnktr_TR_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
        </li>
        <li>
            <asp:LinkButton Text="ENG" CausesValidation="false" ID="lnken_US" Visible="true" runat="server" OnClick="lnken_US_Click"></asp:LinkButton></li>
        <li>
            <asp:LinkButton Text="Беларусь" CausesValidation="false" ID="lnkru_RU" Visible="false" runat="server" OnClick="lnkru_RU_Click" /></li>
        <li>
            <asp:LinkButton Text="العربية" CausesValidation="false" ID="lnkar_AE" Visible="false" runat="server" OnClick="lnkar_AE_Click"></asp:LinkButton></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see above, the language changes with the site button. I want the automatic language to be selected according to the browser language of the site? How can I do it?

Comment: Do you know how the browser communicates the language it wants to to the server?

Comment: Check out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.userlanguages?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_HttpRequest_UserLanguages

Comment: Check the value of this request header in you controller (or code-behind): `accept-language`. I am also from Turkey and my browser sends the following, to get this page (your question :)) `tr-TR,tr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7`. Please also read: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4

Comment: @John - i dont no

Comment: @PoulBak I tried, it didn't work.

Comment: @OguzOzgul Hello, my goal is to open the site according to the browser language. Do you have any information about this subject?

Comment: English only please. The `accept-language` header is the way the browser communicates its language preference. What is the value of this header in your Request?

Comment: @OguzOzgul tr-TR, en-US, ru-RU, ar-AE outputs the format.

Comment: Ok. This means the browser sends a multi-value header (separated with a comma according to the standard). Just split this, and select the appropriate one. If the first language choice does not exist in your system, repeat the same procedure for the next one, and then the next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here.

UPDATE: You are executing this in your master page, so the base.UICulture has changed to Page.UICulture.

Also, please not that the use of Page_Load here is just exemplary. Actually, this answer shows how you can read the accept-language header. You should adapt it to your own context. Question: What happens when the customer clicks one of the buttons in your question? Whatever you do there, do in this code also, instead of setting the UICulture.

For Russian, ru-RU and ru;

For Arabic (there are many) but simply ar-AE, or ar

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string acceptLangaugeHeader = Request.Headers["accept-language"];
    if (acceptLangaugeHeader != null)
    {
        string[] acceptedLangauges = acceptLangaugeHeader.Split(',');
        foreach (string acceptedLanguageWithQuality in acceptedLangauges)
        {
            string acceptedLanguage = acceptedLanguageWithQuality.Split(';')[0];
            // Check here if it is one of the languages you support:
            switch (acceptedLanguage)
            {
                case "en-US":
                case "en":
                    Page.UICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
                    break;
                // DO THE SAME FOR OTHER LANGUAGES
                case "tr-TR":
                case "tr":
                default:
                    Page.UICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("tr-TR");
                    break;

            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Page.UICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("tr-TR");
    }
}
```